# How can I get the name and location of a sound file resource in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a sound.wav file on my resources folder in my C# project. I found that I can use the file using:

```
Properties.Resources.soundImage
```

But the code above gives me a stream. What I need is the name and if it is possible, the path to the file. Is there any way to get them?

Comment: What type of Stream is it?  If it's just a Stream, no.  If it's a FileStream, you can use Name..

Comment: Why are you needing the Path name / file name ?, it should be irrelevant because it is part of your exe and is accessible through the Method you used.

Comment: i want to take the name of the wav file and show it. Also i have a method that extracts the icon of the file and show it, and i wanted the path to take out the icon of the file

Comment: @FernandoSantiago, You *can't*, it is no longer a file. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we see that it is part of `Properties.Resources`, we can tell that it is actually a compiled resource. This means it is embedded in the .NET assembly (.exe or .dll).

While it starts out as a file in your project, the compiler actually plops it into your output file. So when your application is running, there is no filename for you to get.